# Autosigned IIS certificat for an IP

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, certificate

I have a little website in my IIS and i tried to configure HTTPS.
I created an autosigned cert but i still have the NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID if i try to open in google chrome from the internet ( using the public ip adresse).

I don't have any domain name and don't want any domain name.

I wonder where is the probleme with my certificate, is it because i have to set the IP in the certificate ? Is there any simple way to do it ? My website is juste an access from a rest webservice, i just want to use with my IP and using https.

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "autosigned"? If you actually meant "self signed" certificates, they are not trusted anywhere and `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` is expected. Even with a valid certificate, you cannot use IP address as URL, but the domain name. The entire certificate system is built upon domain names, so if you "don't want" any of this, you won't be able to do proper HTTPS connections.

Comment: If you check any valid certificate, you'll find that both of them, `Issue to` and `Issue by` are not IP address. Certificate is used for verify specific domain name. If it can verify IP address, it should always update because most personal machines are using dynamic IP now.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5kHY.png